# OpenCV in c++ to java android

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android

```
static void calculateDelaunayTriangles(Rect rect, vector < Point2f > & points, vector < vector < int > > & delaunayTri) {

    Subdiv2D subdiv(rect);

    for (vector < Point2f > ::iterator it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); it++)
        subdiv.insert( * it);

    vector < Vec6f > triangleList;
    subdiv.getTriangleList(triangleList);
    vector < Point2f > pt(3);
    vector < int > ind(3);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < triangleList.size(); i++) {
        Vec6f t = triangleList[i];
        pt[0] = Point2f(t[0], t[1]);
        pt[1] = Point2f(t[2], t[3]);
        pt[2] = Point2f(t[4], t[5]);

        if (rect.contains(pt[0]) && rect.contains(pt[1]) && rect.contains(pt[2])) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                for (size_t k = 0; k < points.size(); k++)
                    if (abs(pt[j].x - points[k].x) < 1.0 && abs(pt[j].y - points[k].y) < 1)
                        ind[j] = k;

            delaunayTri.push_back(ind);
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to use this function which builds from opencv but this function is C++ function. I want to convert it to java and use it in android. I am a beginner in c++ and I dun know how to convert them. Especially the iterator part I dun know how can it be in java. Can anyone help me to convert it? Thank you very much.

update:
This is the part that I translate

```
 static void calculateDelaunayTriangles(org.opencv.core.Rect rect, Vector<org.opencv.core.Point> points, Vector<Vector<Integer> > delaunayTri){

   // Create an instance of Subdiv2D
   Subdiv2D subdiv = new Subdiv2D(rect);

   // Insert points into subdiv
   for(int i = 0;i < points.size();i++)
   subdiv.insert(points.get(i));

   MatOfFloat6 triangleList = null;
   subdiv.getTriangleList(triangleList);
   Vector<MatOfPoint2f> pt = new Vector<>(3);
   MatOfInt ind = new MatOfInt(3);

   for( int i = 0; i < triangleList.size(); i++ )
   {
       MatOfFloat6 t = triangleList[i];
       pt[0] = new Vector<MatOfPoint2f>(t[0], t[1]);
       pt[1] = new Vector<MatOfPoint2f>(t[2], t[3]);
       pt[2] = new Vector<MatOfPoint2f>(t[4], t[5 ]);

       if ( rect.contains(pt[0]) && rect.contains(pt[1]) && rect.contains(pt[2])){
           for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               for(int k = 0; k < points.size(); k++)
                   if(Math.abs(pt[j].x - points[k].x) < 1.0 && abs(pt[j].y - points[k].y) < 1)
                       ind[j] = k;

           delaunayTri.push_back(ind);
       }
   }

 }
```